# AngularJS ng-valid issue with self-enclosing input tags?

Tags: angularjs

This is the code that I have written while following the angular js documentation available in the official documents.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form novalidate class="css-form">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required><br>
        Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required><br>
        Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="Female">Female <br>
        <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save">
    </form>
    <pre>user = {{ user | json }}</pre>
    <pre>master = {{ master | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

This doesn't work (change the color of the input on blur). How ever this works,

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form novalidate class="css-form">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required /><br>
        Email: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required /><br>
        Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="Female">Female <br>
        <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save">
    </form>
    <pre>user = {{ user | json }}</pre>
    <pre>master = {{ master | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

I do not understand the reason. Would somebody know the reason for this?

Comment: what browser and what doctype are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome with html5

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem. Note should use `name` on form for validation object. Also what version of angular are you using?

Comment: Just ran them in a diff tool, and the only thing that is different is the /> at the lines 3 and 4. Try to change them and tell us what happens.